# Combining two columns into one column returning ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ora-01722

```
SELECT X.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + X.LASTNAME as names FROM B_CUSTOMERS X;
```

returns the error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

All research I have done indicates that this is a perfectly viable method for combining columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `||`

```
SELECT X.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || X.LASTNAME as names 
FROM B_CUSTOMERS X
```